# Are there any examples in any language of words beginning with the sound [θð]?

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, dental-fricative

While I have some difficulty pronouncing a hypothetical word *ending* with [θð], it seems perfectly possible to have such a sound at the beginning or in the middle of a word.

Is the sound [θð] ever used to begin words in any language?

Comment: If you mean phonetically, I would guess that Kabyle Berber does.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by the sound þð? I'm assuming you mean those letters as they are used in Icelandic i.e. [θð] using the IPA, but it would be good to have confirmation. It's also unclear what some of the vowel letters you use mean. I'm assuming ö is either [ø] or [œ], and ō is [o:], but I'm unsure how to interpret your ë (I'm also assuming ə is used for [ə])

Comment: @Tristan Edited.

Comment: I would bet that word-initial /ð/ in English in many cases involves a stage with dental frication but not voicing. But if you're asking phonemically, though, I can't even think of a language that allows consecutive homorganic consonants that differ only in voicing in the same syllable.

Comment: Affricates like /tθ/ or /dð/ are relatively commonplace word-initially. A sequence of two homorganic fricatives differing only in voicedness, on the other hand, is not something I’ve ever come across. Initial /fv/, /xɣ/ and /sz/ are equally unfamiliar.

Comment: @Nardog I wouldn’t bet on that. Word-initial /ð/ would more typically be affricated with a preceding /d/, rather than initially devoiced, I’d say.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I find it likely when it's preceded by a voiceless fricative. If it said utterance-initial instead of word-initial, I indeed wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: More to the point, what made you ask this question? A succession of consonants differing only in voicing is already pretty rare, as are languages with both voiced and voiceless dental fricatives. The question is so specific it's befuddling.

Comment: @Nardog I suppose I could have asked this question more generally about “word-initial sequences of homorganic consonants differing only in voicedness”, if I had known the terminology.

Comment: @Nardog - The Russian word for “behind” is _сзади_ (szadi) which is /'szadi/ phonemically, but phonetically it's [ˈzːadʲɪ].